# Passing information to modal in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-modal

Im attempting to change the way that my table currently works. Right now the table is created by looping through all of the samples passed to it through the context in views.py of my Django app, and that works fine. The change i want to make however is to create a modal when the delete sample button is clicked show the user a warning message before they delete it. The problem im running into is that the `{{ sample.id }}` in the modal is identifying the first sample in the table (seems to not be part of the for loop). Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<table class="table table-themed sample-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th><th>Mh to Mh</th><th>Shot & Sec</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
    {% for sample in samples %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ sample.status }}</td>
            <td>{{ sample.mh_to_mh }}</td>
            <td>{{ sample.shot_and_sec }}</td>
            <td>{{ sample.date_created }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'contracts:view_sample' sample.id %}">View Details</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{% url 'contracts:delete_sample' sample.id %}">Delete</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete Modal</button>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Sample</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Are you sure that you want to delete this {{ sample.id }} sample?</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{% url 'contracts:delete_sample' sample.id %}">Delete</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Not as good with my html as other languages, thanks for the idea! I naming each id like `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{sample.id}}">Delete</button>'
                    '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{sample.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">` and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple elements in HTML should not have the same ID. Although no error is thrown, the JS will always refer to the first element with the ID (in this case `myModal`)
It is better to move the modal out and pass the data needed when you open it. Have your HTML as such

```
<table class="table table-themed sample-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Mh to Mh</th>
        <th>Shot & Sec</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
    {% for sample in samples %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ sample.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ sample.mh_to_mh }}</td>
        <td>{{ sample.shot_and_sec }}</td>
        <td>{{ sample.date_created }}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'contracts:view_sample' sample.id %}">View Details</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{% url 'contracts:delete_sample' sample.id %}">Delete</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                    data-id="{{ sample.id }}"
                    data-url="{% url 'contracts:delete_sample' sample.id %}">Delete Modal
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Sample</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure that you want to delete this <span id="sampleId"></span> sample?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="" id="actualDeleteBtn">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need some JavaScript to set the correct values from data attributes

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
    $("#sampleId").text($(event.relatedTarget).data('id'));
    $("#actualDeleteBtn").attr('href', $(event.relatedTarget).data('url'));
})
```